# Is Facebook app-scoped id global unique?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Since Facebook make different ids for same user in different apps in API V2.0, we should change our attaching systems to fit this.

For the reason that I wanna make less change on our system, I need to know whether the Facebook app-scoped id global unique, in another word, there were have two apps, will the ids conflict when I save only the user app-scoped id in a same hash?

More details following.

I have two apps in a business, so each app could get the app-scoped id for another. I already have a system storing user's information unique index by the user app-scoped id of First app. Now I need to save these two apps user data in the same MySQL table, and we use the ids_for_business API to confirm whether the same user has registered in another app, to decide make a new register or login as a new user of our system. If the app-scoped id is globally unique, we could just act as what I am saying. But if the app-scoped id will be same for different user, that our user system will identify different user as a same user in our system, so we have to make a big change to follow Facebook.

Help me please...

**Example like this, id of UserA on AppC is 33, would the id of UserB on AppD be 33?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, The IDs are globally unique:

The ID you get for a specific user who has logged into your app / granted you permission will not change, 
Two apps never get the same ID to reference different users - an app scoped ID is globally unique and references a specific {app, user} pair

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and my global unique means "different user would not get a same id in different apps", and it was not mention on Facebook's official page, may you confirm this?

Comment: @lgy  where did you find the IDs are globally unique? Would you please show me the source ( in Official Docs, etc ) ?

Comment: How can you confirm that? @WizKid